# Pulling String from Database. Says Cannot Implicitly Convert to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, xsd

In my database I have a field that is storing a simple string. The user can edit it, as it will be used as the text on a button later.

The storing of the string is working fine, but when I try to pull the string out again in case the user wants to edit it, the code behind is showing me the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'store.storeProductsDataTable' to 'string'
```

I have an XSD with a super basic get statement to retrieve the text and the field in the database is flagged as type text. Like I mentioned, it's storing the string great. Also on the same page, it successfully retrieves the product's name, description, price, etc using the same method.

All I am trying to do with the string is apply it to a textbox with the following code:

```
customBuyNowText.Text = pdb.getBuyNowText(pID);
```

Any suggestions on what I could be missing for it to cause this error?

Comment: can you show the signature of getBuyNowText? it won't be returning string

Comment: agreed @naveen, the return type of getBuyNowText would probably be a datatable or more specifically a store.storeProductsDataTable according to the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try this yet again in C#:  if it's a datatable, try:

```
DataTable dt   = pdb.getBuyNowText(pID);
customBuyNowText.Text = dt.Rows[0]["your_column_name"].ToString();
```

Comment: to avoid null reference errors, you should check that the datatable has at least 1 row, and that the value isn't a DBNull.  There's a billion ways to do that, however you want to do it.

Comment: @stephenbayer: i just changed the column index to name

Comment: @stephenbayer - DBNull isn't an issue. `DBNull.Value.ToString() == String.Empty`

Comment: @naveen, your mixing c# and VB.NET on this post.  @Greg - I'm paranoid about using nulls and DBNulls.

Comment: @stephenbayer: the question is in c# :)

Comment: i thought it was tagged as VB.NET, i had multiple windows open, messing with my mind.  :)

Comment: I tried the code you suggested @stephenbayer and while it didn't error out in the code, when I attempted to view the page I got the fun 

   System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints. 

It baffles me because it's such a simple thing I am trying to do. I have multiple fields in this table doing the exact same thing just with different text.

Comment: Ok, I feel silly. After coming back from lunch and re-reading your answer with fresh eyes, I thought "wait, it shouldn't BE a datatable." So I went back and revisited the query and realize I had created wrong in the first place, creating a datatable rather than simple select statement. Thanks for your help.